# Binding energy per nucleon

Tags: binding-energy

This graph shows the binding energy per nucleon which is the energy required for extract a nucleon from a nucleus. From the fermi gas model of nucleus I know that both protons and neutrons are in a potential well and, due to Pauli principle, protons and neutrons have different energy. The question is, how can the binding energy be the same for a neutron in the last state of the potential well equal to that of the neutorn in the lower state?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The graph says nothing about any particular nucleon. It says something about the whole nucleus.

Comment: Since that nucleons have different energy because they are fermion, how can the energy required to extract one of them be the same for every nucleon?

Comment: The graph says nothing about the energy to extract some given nucleon. It is about the average binding energy across all the nucleons.

Comment: What Jon said. Note that the vertical axis of the graph is labelled "**Average** binding energy per nucleon".